# How to make a GameObject ignore a camera effect?

Tags: unity, camera, post-processing, bloom

I have a 2D game and I wanted to apply bloom to the main GameObjects so I attached the effect onto the main camera, however the background also gets affected by the bloom and it gets all shiny. How can I make it ignore the bloom effect?

Comment: I never did that with camera effects. But you can give a try to create a new camera, set culling mask only to **background**. **background** is the layer applied to your background. Also remove **background** from culling mask of Main Camera

Comment: @HamzaHasan Isn't that how it's usually done? Anyway, I did what you said, but now the background is not shown on the main camera. The main camera's depth is 0 while the no-fx-camera's depth is 1

Comment: Also set skybox to don't clear of second or both cameras. And revert the depth sequence.

Comment: @HamzaHasan And now the GameObjects disappear

Comment: I can't say anything without having anything. But you can manage with it. Play with the attributes

Comment: @HamzaHasan It doesn't work in any way. The background always gets the bloom.

Comment: hmm, ok let me do some work on it

Comment: @HamzaHasan I am using Unity's "Bloom (Optimized)" effect by the way

Answer (score 2):

Bloom effect in Unity is actually a post effect which means it works after all the GameObjects have been rendered by the camera, and it can't be seperately affected.

The only way you can do this is use two cameras, one for the main GameObjects and one for the background, and properly set the layer and Camera's culling mask of the cameras

Check this doc for more detail
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html

Comment: This works ok but Game Objects on the upper layer will always be rendered above the others (so will appear in front of walls for example).

Answer (score -1):

Since the Unity bloom effects are post processed, they apply to the whole screen, so they can't be controlled by camera layers.
Fixed it by not using it.